# How to implement Netlify form with React.js contact form?

Tags: reactjs, netlify

I need to implement a stateful react.js and material-ui form with netlify form.

Also referred to this post as well :[Form Handling with a Stateful React Form](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2017/07/20/how-to-integrate-netlifys-form-handling-in-a-react-app/#form-handling-with-a-stateful-react-form)

How can I do that? thanks !!!

Comment: Have you find a solution ?

Comment: I don't fix this problem! please share with me if you find a solution

Comment: [My github repo](https://github.com/sbayrak/suatbayrak-portfolio-materialui) you can use my repo as for example. Take a look inside `public/index.html` i have a netlify form there and also check out my `Contact.js` component.